# Softlayer object Expiration date to Automatic delete from Object´s Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

Before start using Softlayer I´ve been using AWS services, and it Object´s Storage service has a funcionallity where you could define what was the life time of a file and automatically this file was deleted from the Bucket.

I´ve tried a lot of things using API and Control Panel to do this but without success.

Can you have some way to do this? or could you give me a better way to proceed?

Thanks 
Best,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

Using the portal you just need to go to the file, then mark it and in the right pane you will see the option expires at:

[image]

using the API you just need to set the following header with a Unix Epoch timestamp to the file using the POST method:

```
"X-Delete-At" : "1317070737"
```

Softlayer's Object storage is based in Open stack you can see more about how to set the expiration for Open Stack here

- https://community.runabove.com/kb/en/object-storage/how-to-schedule-deletion-of-objects.html
- http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_expiring_objects.html

For more information about how to use Softlayer's Object storage API see:

- https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

Regards